# AutoResetEvent how i can write on listview

Tags: c#, vb.net, listview, events

how can I write on listview called " LivStampaEventi "
I would write the events written to the Event Log windows in real time ,
I should use delegates , if so can you tell me how?
 thanks to you all

```
  Private Shared signal As AutoResetEvent
Private Sub Form1_Load_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    scelta = ""
    Me.Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Me.Threaddammiora)) 'creo il thread
    Me.Thread.Start() 'lancio il thread

    width_rem = LivStampaEventi.Width
    Height_rem = LivStampaEventi.Height
    Dim remoteEventLogs() As EventLog

    Dim log As EventLog
    For Each log In remoteEventLogs
        cmb_tutti_i_log.Items.Add(log.Log)
    Next log

    signal = New AutoResetEvent(False)
    Dim myNewLog As New EventLog("PMIS_A2A", System.Environment.MachineName)

    AddHandler myNewLog.EntryWritten, AddressOf Me.MyOnEntryWritten
    myNewLog.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    myNewLog.WriteEntry("PMIS_A2A", EventLogEntryType.Information)

    signal.WaitOne()
End Sub


Public Sub MyOnEntryWritten(ByVal [source] As Object, ByVal e As EntryWrittenEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("In event handler")
    signal.Set()
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    list.Clear()
    list.Add(e.Entry.EventID.ToString())
    list.Add(e.Entry.Message.ToString())
    list.Add(e.Entry.EntryType.ToString())
    list.Add(e.Entry.TimeWritten.ToString())
    list.Add(e.Entry.TimeGenerated.ToString())
    list.Add(e.Entry.Index.ToString())
    LivStampaEventi.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(list.ToArray))
    If (e.Entry.EntryType.ToString = "Warning") Then
        LivStampaEventi.Items(LivStampaEventi.Items.Count - 1).BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Else
        If (e.Entry.EntryType.ToString = "Error") Then
            LivStampaEventi.Items(LivStampaEventi.Items.Count - 1).BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            LivStampaEventi.Items(LivStampaEventi.Items.Count - 1).BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
    End If
End Sub ' MyOnEntryWritten
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? I mean, what you expect and don't get from your code?

Comment: Also, does the thread you are starting (with Threaddammiora) matter with your problem?

Comment: LivStampaEventi.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(list.ToArray))->
Additional information: Operazione cross-thread not valid: 
problem with multithread

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHInvalidOperation.WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true

Comment: Add `myNewLog.SynchronizingObject = Me` and get rid of the AutoResetEvent,  helps you to avoiding having to learn about writing thread-safe code for a while.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to set your `list` properties from a non UI thread, which result in the exception you get.
The MSDN link you cite give a solution:
In your MyOnEntryWritten, test InvokeRequired

```
If list.InvokeRequired then // true if not in the UI thread
    list.Invoke(...) // use a delegate for MyOnEntryWritten 
Else
    // the actual code
End If
```

To create param for Invoke, check your link